# How can Twisted interact with command line programs? Can Node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, twisted, event-driven

I *think* what I need for a couple of projects it event-driven programming. This led me to Twisted (Python) and Node.js (Javascript).

One thing I need is interaction with command line programs, which take their time to finish and print stuff now and then to standard output.

I found no good tutorial for Twisted, and I found nothing on how to get Twisted with non-network-related programming.

Questions:

Is there a tutorial which covers non-network stuff with Twisted?

Should I better look at Node.js? If so, why?

Are there alternatives to event-driven programming which abstract the problem better? (I know, there are a lot which abstract it worse; please don’t mention them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to react to socket events, or gui events of some kind, you really dont need twisted.  If you are waiting for the user to input data, then standard command shell or repl designs will work.  Those applications are purely synchronous.

Of course, if you are talking about running a subprocess from a daemon (or an otherwise already running twisted application), https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html

Comment: I need to interact with dozens of command line programs at once. – It’s not a daemon, I don’t wait for user input and it’s not synchronous. – The link is good, though. :-)

Comment: Edited for clarification that the link applies not only to daemons, but to any twisted application.  Twisted applications are typically daemons, and thus I assume thats the use case when twisted is being used, but by no means is it only for daemons, or that non-daemons are difficult in twisted.

Comment: Someone even downvoted your answer?? (I gave a +1.) – But I still believe that the whole answers is crap except the link. Why? There are many scenarios where Twisted makes sense. Not just socket, GUI and daemons, so why insisting that _I_ don’t need Twisted?

Comment: Because when most people are writing command shells they don't need to be asynchronous - I have seen far to many people spin up twisted to do a task, then wait for all deferreds to return.  At that point all you are doing is contributing to the heat death of the universe.  I originally thought you were asking about writing a command shell, thus the first part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Twisted application to interact with command-line programs by calling them and capturing their output, you can do that with [spawnProcess](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorProcess.html) as described at Tritium21's link. It runs asynchronously, so your Twisted app will carry on processing, and can run other programs in the meantime.

If you want to run a command-line program which will have some effect on the Twisted app, you can have Twisted [listen on a socket](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html) and have the programs connect to it to send commands. Again, Twisted can talk to many programs at once provided you write the processing code asynchronously. One really good way to talk to the server is with AMP, the [Asynchronous Messaging Protocol](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html).

And of course, the same app can do both of those things at once, and more besides.

Comment: The former I want to do.